# Suspend on level of login, not workstation - possible issue in multiuser system (Ubuntu, Mint)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, suspend

I noted in Linux Mint and newest Ubuntu 18, that suspend functionality is setup (sudo/root is not needed for suspend setting) and working on level of login/user.

For example, I had 3 users logged on, in Ubuntu, then laptop went to suspend (on lid close) when I had one user session on screen, then resume. Now when I switched to other user session (using ctrl-alt-f), I saw user screen, then automatically in several seconds laptop went to suspend. IMHO not reasonable behaviour.

Is there a reason for suspend to be implemented that way? Is it same for other Linux desktop distros? How complex could it be to change kernel to have suspend working for workstation, not user? I'm ready to help make it happen if my help would be of use.

Comment: I would not think that the functionality would be in the kernel. The kernel probably needs to do the suspend, but deciding when to do it should, and hopefully is a user mode task.

Comment: I have had similar thoughts. How do I set up power management as a global/system level policy?